# How can I use the '>' redirector operator when running an external command?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following command in the installation section of my install script.

```
Execute-Process -Path mbsacli.exe -Parameters '/xmlout /catalog wsusscn2.cab >result.xml' -WindowStyle Hidden
```

If I just run:

```
Execute-Process -Path mbsacli.exe -Parameters '/xmlout /catalog wsusscn2.cab' -WindowStyle Hidden
```

then the process works fine, but as soon as I add the >reports.xml to the command, I get "Too many parameters passed" from the mbsacli.exe tool. However, according to the mbsacli tool, this is the proper way to run the command:

```
MBSACLI /xmlout /catalog c:\temp\wsusscn2.cab /unicode >results.xml
```

Is Powershell hitting the '>' character and going something weird?

FYI -

Comment: Instead of `>` use `| out-file`

Comment: `Execute-Process -Path mbsacli.exe -Parameters '/xmlout /catalog wsusscn2.cab' -WindowStyle Hidden  > result.xml` maybe as well. Since you are not passing the redirection to `mbsacli` which is what the error is trying to tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you pasted the command interpreter is parsing your command and outputting STDOUT to a text file. In the one you pasted you're passing params that Execute-Process doesn't know how to handle. Instead try this:

```
Execute-Process -Path cmd.exe -Parameters "/C MBSACLI /xmlout /catalog C:\fullpath\wsusscn2.cab >results.xml" -WindowStyle Hidden
```